# Import own Python module on Kaggle

Tags: python, module, kaggle

I am new to this and very new to Kaggle.

I am trying to replicate this notebook:

https://www.kaggle.com/bibhash123/chest-x-ray-abnormalities-baseline-tf-keras

There one person wrote a module `from utilities_x_ray`

https://www.kaggle.com/bibhash123/utilities-x-ray

How to import it? It looks like `utilities_x_ray` is not directly specified in the second link.

As a result, I get an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities_x_ray
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities_x_ray
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-79d7808e32c5> in <module>
 11 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 12 get_ipython().system('pip install utilities_x_ray')
---> 13 import utilities_x_ray
 14 from utilities_x_ray import read_xray,showXray
 15 from tqdm import tqdm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities_x_ray'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to `pip install` the utility file. Rather, just include the `utilities_x_ray.py` file in the same directory that you run the python notebook.

The python notebook looks for files within the same directory whenever importing as well as those modules that were installed via `pip`.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what does the same directory mean if it is on Kaggle everything. Any specific tip?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the script content from https://www.kaggle.com/bibhash123/utilities-x-ray into your working directory and save it as utilities_x_ray.py
Hope this w'll be helpfull

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what does the same directory mean if it is on Kaggle everything. Any specific tip?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider downloading both the chest-x-ray-abnormalities-baseline-tf-keras.ipynb as [image] and the utilities_x_ray.py [image] Please make sure that they are into the same folder... After that, you'll need to install the pydimcom and scikit-image using pip install pydicom scikit-image

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the packages directly from the GIt repository:

`!pip install git+https://github.com/dkriegner/xrayutilities.git`